# Coalesce different with case

Tags: sql, postgresql

i get confused in learning coalesce, I am new to sql.

example :

```
select case when value is null then 1 
    else value end as value 
from table
```

and

```
select coalesce(value, 1)  
from table
```

and in the tutorial I see  in internet there are like

```
select coalesce (arg_1, arg_2, arg_3)
```

if I make

```
select coalesce(value, 1, 2)
```

how I can make to show the return value is 2?

Comment: The [Postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html#AEN12663) give a clear explanation as to how the function works. That's a good place to start when you don't understand how a function works. `The COALESCE function returns the first of its arguments that is not null.`

Comment: `Coalesce` returns the first non-null value it matches.  So in your last case, `1` is not null, so it will be returned if `value` is null and `2` could never be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `query` with the first and second will reproduce the same result, But you are wrong understanding the `Coalesce` concept.

Definition in [**Documentation Postgresql**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL)

> The COALESCE function returns the first of its arguments that is not
>   null. Null is returned only if all arguments are null.

So it means it will return the first argument that is `not null`, it is not like `case` statement with condition like `true` or `false`

Let's try with example :

```
select coalesce(null, 1)
```

It will return `1` like the query you show, or

```
select coalesce(null, null, 1)
```

It will return `1` too even `1` in the `arg_3` and how about there are 2 value `not null`?

```
select coalesce(null, 1, 2)
```

It will return `1`. Why? Like in the documentation said "**returns the first of its arguments that is not null**" so when there is 2 value `not null` the first argument have `not null` value will get return

You can check this demo and try :

[**Demo<>Fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2a7685cf47a01bf274650ab968b586e1)

Hope it helps

Comment: Simple and great explanation, Thanks :)

Comment: Gladly to help.. :)